# When is Pontrjagin ring isomorphic to Cohomology ring (under coefficient $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $\Bbb{Z}$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-groups

This question is motivated by the result of Poincare duality,

> Definition: Suppose $X$ is an $H$-space (or in particular, assume $X$ is a topological group that can be represented as a manifold...). We know that the Pontrjagin product is given by the formula
> $$H_i(X)\otimes H_j(X)\overset{\times}{\longrightarrow}H_{i+j}(X\times X)\longrightarrow H_{i+j}(X)$$

Now, I'm interested in the following question:

- What are the necessary and sufficient condition for the following isomorphism? $$H_*(X;R)\cong H^*(X;R)$$
  where $H_*(X)$ is the Pontrjagin ring and $H^*(X)$ is the cohomology ring, both with coefficients in a ring $R$. In particular, I'm interested in the case $R=\Bbb{Z}$.

<s>Moreover, can we actually construct this isomorphism using cap product component-wise?</s>

---

I took a look on a few examples with $\Bbb{Z}$ coefficient, but most of them don't satisfy the criterion:

1. $n$-dim torus $T^n=\prod_{i=1}^nS^1$. It is a topological group with addition of angles as the operation. We know that $H^*(T^n;\Bbb{Z})\cong\Lambda[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$, and $H_*(T^n;\Bbb{Z})\cong\Lambda[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ by direct computation using the property of dual Hopf algebra. So I think this is one example of that isomorphism. In other words, what kind of conditions does $X$ needs to satisfy in order to make the two rings isomorphic?
2. $S^1\subset\Bbb{C}$ (resp. $S^3\subset\Bbb{H}$) has an $H$-space structure, and $H^*(S^1;\Bbb{Z})\cong\Lambda[x^1]\cong\Lambda[x_1]\cong H_*(S^1;\Bbb{Z})$, similarly for $S^3\subset\Bbb{H}$. Because the dual of $$\Delta(x^1)^2=(x^1\otimes 1+1\otimes x^1)^2=(x^1)^2\otimes 1+x^1\otimes x^1-x\otimes x+1\otimes (x^1)^2=0$$ gives the clue of the product operation in the dual Hopf algebra, which implies that $\Lambda_\Bbb{Z}[x^i]$ is self-dual, when $|x^i|$ odd.
3. This is just a guess... I think maybe $SU(n)$ satisfies this under $\Bbb{Z}$ coefficient, because I have a feeling that it's somehow related to the complex projective space, but I need $SU(n)$'s cell structure to rigorously compute $H^*$ and $H_*$.

Running out of examples...

Because Hatcher mentions "dual Hopf algebra" in his book, I think it may be simpler to search for such algebras and then realize them as spaces. Thus, I think we need Hopf algebras that are self-dual, in this case... However, to make this dualization useful, $H^j(X;\Bbb{Z})$ is required to be free for all $j$. This completely blocks my attempt because there are too many things to consider...

For other coefficients group like $\Bbb{Z}_p$, I have no idea what's going to happen.

**Edit:**

As @Tyrone has pointed out, there is an answer in $\Bbb{Q}$ for finite $H$-space.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the Pontryagin ring is the dual Hopf algebra of the cohomology ring? So perhaps letting go of topological examples, one might first ask for some natural examples of Hopf algebras that satisfy or fail self-duality.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer When $H^j$ is free in all dimension, they are dual Hopf algebra to each other. For your second sentence, that's what I'm confused, I don't know how to systematically find those algebras. Simple examples like divided polynomial ring and polynomial rings are NOT self-dual, but exterior algebra is self dual (at least in $\Bbb{Z}$ coefficient).

Comment: There are plenty of example of exteior algebras, and these are self-dual. eg. tori $H_*U_n$, $H_*(SO_n;\mathbb{Z}_2)$. In fact the rational Pontrjagin ring of any finite H-complex is an exterior algebra. The duality will never be induced by the cap product, however because the Hopf duality switches the products and coproducts.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for your comment. Do you know any reference that contains a proof of that result? (Probably it contains knowledge that I haven't learned yet...)

Comment: Which part would you like, Kevin? There are computations of the Pontrjagin rings of the classical groups in Hatcher's book which are very readable. For a more advance discussion see R. Kane's book *The homology of Hopf spaces*. Let me know if you are looking for something specific.

Comment: @Tyrone Actually, I'm reading Hatcher's book and this question is just naturally motivated. Since there is a clear condition on $\Bbb{Q}$, I think it might be valid to generalize that to other kinds of fields also (not sure), and I'm particularly interested in $\Bbb{Z}$ because things seem to vary significantly in integers...